# Why does MSVC 16.7 treat function overload involving conversion from long to int ambiguous?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, language-lawyer, c++20

I have updated my MSVC to 16.7 and now he complains about the following code:

> error C2668: ...  ambiguous call to overloaded function

```
void f(int){
}

void f(double){
}

int main()
{   
    long l = 5;
    static_assert(sizeof(long)==4,"");
    f(l);
}
```

It used to compile in older compilers
https://godbolt.org/z/PG7GTY

I understand why GCC and Clang complain, since their long is 8 bytes, but why would MSVC reject this code when long on MSVC is 32bit, aka same as int.

Does C++ standard requires this to be ambiguous, or is it fine for implementation to consider long as int for purposes of overload resolution if the are "same underlying" type.

If it matters I am compiling with C++20 flag on MSVC.

Comment: Which function should the compiler choose? It's unrelated to the size. Both functions need one implicit cast.

Comment: @ThomasSablik as mentioned in the question on msvc long and int are same type in a sense they have the same range of values and same size.

Comment: No, they are not the same type. They have the same size and probably the same bit structure but they are different types. The difference between a strong type and an alias is very important.

Comment: @ThomasSablik -- re: "one implicit cast" -- that should be "one implicit **conversion**". There is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First the compiler looks for a function that can be called without implicit conversion. If it finds exactly one it calls it.

If it finds none it looks for a function that can be called with one implicit conversion. In your example both functions need exactly one implicit conversion. That makes the code ambiguous.

The size of the types is absolutely irrelevant.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Viable_functions